# Difference between current sense amplifier filter configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, current-measurement

I am trying to figure out what is the effect of the different connections of the C3 capacitor in this circuit. It is the classical difference amplifier configuration used in current sense with some filtering. 
C3 is placed there to match C2 which is used for bandwidth limiting.
Does it change something by connecting C3 to GND of 1.65V ? 
Is it correct to say that in AC 1.65 and GND are connected together so C3 connection doesn't care?
Thanks
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does it change something by connecting C3 to GND of 1.65V ? Is it
>   correct to say that in AC 1.65 and GND are connected together so C3
>   connection doesn't care?*

That is correct. As far as AC is concerned, a DC voltage source is the same as ground so, providing your mid-rail generator (1.65 volts) is bolstered up with bulk capacitance (if needed), it should behave the same.

Comment: The first config will couple any AC noise on 1.65V to the input.  Second config would help reduce such noise.

Comment: Unless the ground is noisier than the 1.65v. :)

Comment: @rdtsc - surely that's actually not the case. Since the output load is referred to the same ground you may actually require that the noise be transferred through the amplifier. The best way however is to ensure that the output load ground, the ground for C3 and the 1.65V DC source are all controlled extremely closely so there is no difference in noise voltage.